# What kind of cable input is this in the back of a 2001 chevy malibu?

Tags: chevrolet, audio

In my malibu, there is a cd/aux button, but no input for an aux. I did some research and found that inputs can be added from the back of the radio. This picture is the back of the radio, and the port looks like an audio port, but I can't tell exactly what kind. I think its a midi connector, but I'm not sure. If it is, would a midi (or whatever it is) to aux cord work when plugging in a phone? Or do I need some other gadget?

[image]

Comment: I don't know what it is, but it's unlikely to be a [midi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI) connector, which is for musical instruments.

Comment: Remote Multi disc cd player?

Comment: Looks like the antenna

Answer (score 1):

The photo doesn't show well what the connector looks like. If there are several contacts in the black center section of the connector, it's one of the many [DIN connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector) types.

AUX ports come in many variations, so you'll need more information to make sure you get the correct type. Do a search for "[radio type number] AUX in" and you might find connectors made for this port.

The AUX may also be on some of the pins of one of the large multipin connectors.

I've done some searching, and did not find the pinouts of those connectors: several sites claim to have them, but none match the photo.

Going by [this site](https://www.crutchfield.com/car/outfitmycar/mycar.aspx) (and several others) there doesn't seem to be an adapter that will allow you to add an AUX input.

Comment: it is the antenna connector.